# Permission Denied to Root when modifying schema.sql in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: mysql, radius

When running the following command as root using "sudo su -", I receive a permission denied error:

```
mysql -u root -p radius &lt; /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/sql/main/mysql/schema.sql
```

I am unable to continue installing Radius due to this issue:
[Screenshot of the permission denied error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8315.png)

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens: You get an error at command execution for the command `lt`.

Then bash tries to execute the file `/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/sql/main/mysql/schema.sql` which is not an executable.

Try

```
mysql -u root -p radius < /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/sql/main/mysql/schema.sql
```